# Execute an external application as root - problem

Tags: external, root, execute

Good morning:

I'm trying to run an external application that needs to be executed
as root. I have to read the lines from exit after the execution
of this application but it says "permission denied", as if the
its not been done correctly. I've been thinking over a time
and I can not move forward. The code is as follows:

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
String[] command = {external application command};
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando);
InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
try
{
   bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new
       InputStreamReader(inputStream),8192);
   String line = null;
   while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
   {
      System.out.println("read line:"+line );
   }
}
catch (IOException ioe)
{
  ioe.printStackTrace();
}
process.waitFor();
```

Does anyone know why not let me run the command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any errors when trying to run `su`? (I imagine you would, since `su` will probably open the terminal directly to prompt for a password; `su` won't just read standard input for a password.)

Do you have any errors or success when trying to run a *simple* program, like `/usr/bin/cat /etc/passwd`? Might as well start simple and see if you can get it to work before trying for more complicated programs.

Comment: My code works fine if I put the command is executed
a "ls-l" for example. However, I am trying to run a
application that access a device /dev/xxxx butneed
root access. I have rooted my mobile and it works if I run the command from console/terminal without problems, but since the source code tells me "Permission denied."

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

what about trying

```
sudo -iu root
```

instead of su

Comment: My code works fine if I put the command is executed
a "ls-l" for example. However, I am trying to run a
application that accesses a device / dev / xxxx that you need
root. I have rooted mobile and it works if I run the command
from terminal without problems, but since the source code tells me
"Permission denied."

Thanks.